# JQUERY - remove array from a multidimensional array with key

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove an array in a multidimensional array if the id is the same off the given one.

```
var test_arr = [{"name":"qqq", "city":"it","id":"123456"}, {"name":"ggg", "city":"uk","id":"777456"}];

var result = test_arr.filter(function(v,i) {  
     if (v[0] === '123456'){ test_arr.splice(i,1) } 
}); 

//alert( test_arr[0].id)
alert(result)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ofLg0vq5/2/

How Could I do this?

Comment: `var result = test_arr.filter(v => v.id !== '123456' )`

Comment: NB: this question has nothing to do with jQuery..., but JavaScript. Please update the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your current solution is that you're not using [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) correctly. `.filter` expects its passed function to return a `boolean`. If `true` is returned, the current element will be kept in the newly generated array. If it is `false`, the current element will be omitted. So, instead of trying to remove the element from `test_arr` using `.splice`, use `.filter` to decide what stays and what gets removed.

Also, note that in your example `v` is referring to a given element (a particular object) in your `test_array`. Thus, you do not need to target index `0` of your object, but rather you need to get the `id` of the current object.

```js
var test_arr = [{"name":"qqq", "city":"it","id":"123456"}, {"name":"ggg", "city":"uk","id":"777456"}];

test_arr = test_arr.filter(function(elem) {  
  return elem.id !== '123456'; 
}); 

console.log(test_arr); // [{"name": "ggg", "city": "uk", "id": "777456"}]
```

If you want a "cleaner" solution you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
test_arr = test_arr.filter(({id}) => id !== '123456'); // [{"name": "ggg", "city": "uk", "id": "777456"}]
```

```js
var test_arr = [{"name":"qqq", "city":"it","id":"123456"}, {"name":"ggg", "city":"uk","id":"777456"}];

test_arr = test_arr.filter(({id}) => id !== '123456'); // [{"name": "ggg", "city": "uk", "id": "777456"}]
console.log(test_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nick had given solution without `.splice`, but
If for any reason you still want to go for `.splice` solution, you can try below code.

You are were checking `id` in wrong way, in below solution it will remove all objects with `id` - 123456

http://jsfiddle.net/u0qshcvf/2/